# Can't launch app with Sherlock action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, dalvik, dex

I have this problem when trying to launch my app, it's strange because yesterday it was working fine.

```
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pe.com.livetrack.client/pe.com.livetrack.client.activities.BootSherlockFragmentActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pe.com.livetrack.client.activities.BootSherlockFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/pe.com.livetrack.client-1.apk]
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2697)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2051)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4645)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pe.com.livetrack.client.activities.BootSherlockFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/pe.com.livetrack.client-1.apk]
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
01-18 12:19:40.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     ... 11 more
```

Things I have done trying to make it works:

1. Clean and build project
2. Clean and build ActionbarSherlock project
3. Chechk the Manifest for the activity and it is registered.
4. Check  the bin library for the class and the class is there.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name="pe.com.livetrack.client.activities.BootSherlockFragmentActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

BootFragment

```
public class BootSherlockFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        IOController ioController = new IOController(getApplicationContext());
        UserData userData = ioController.loadUserData();
        if (!(userData.getAccount().equals("") && userData.getUser().equals(""))) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainMenuSherlockActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.boot);

            TextView textViewVersion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boot_textview_version);
        try {
            String versionName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
            textViewVersion.setText(textViewVersion.getText() + " "
                    + versionName);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            textViewVersion.setText("");
        }

        new LoadUserDataAndGoToMainMenu(this).execute();
    }

}
```

Also I have the libraries referenced

[image: Libraries]

The Java Build Path here:

[image: Java Build path]

Any idea what can I do?

I re-reference the actionBarSherlock library and it works, I modified the files project.properties , .classpath and other files with a text editor (Notepad++) and it worked with 5 projects that I was getting the same error, but with one didn't work. Now I am getting this error:

```
[2014-01-21 18:19:41 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2014-01-21 18:19:41 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

If I clean and build the project or try to modify the files with the editor but I get the above error ClassNotFoundException.
What is wrong?

Comment: have you given the reference of ActionBarSherlock Linbrary in your project?

Comment: @El_Mochiq can you show the snap shot of your build path. right click on your project properties- java build path. check the order export tab

Comment: Wich one of the four tabs? Source, Project, Libraries or order and export?

Comment: @El_Mochiq the order export tab.

Comment: @El_Mochiq seems alright. try re-referrencing actiobarsherlock

Comment: It crashes again, I didn't change anything just trying to launch it again, and obviously I re-reference the libraries , clean, build, nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was deleting the android-support-v4.jar from the ActionBarSherlock project, build the ABS project again, re-referencing, clean the project and build it again.